# Mongoose insert based on filter

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I need to insert a document in Mongodb using Mongoose when a certain condition is met. How can I achieve this by using a single query?
I know I can do this using find and create functions but I want to do it in single db query. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not filtering (without queries, but plain JavaScript) your data before adding it via Mongoose?

Comment: So the filter is itself on Mongodb query. It's like if status is not equal to 1 then insert new doc.Status is one of the doc properties.